# Simple error : Wordpress Gutenberg Block not outputting php variable in javascript console. Any help appreciated

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, project-gutenberg, gutenberg-reusable-block

I'm creating a gutenberg dynamic block. The problem is my I can't access the attributes value outside of render.php , even in my main plugin random-jokes.php file.

My console is just outputting this [image]

not the concatenated value that I want it to give me in output here is my plugin main file code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Random Jokes
 * Description:       Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.
 * Requires at least: 6.1
 * Requires PHP:      7.0
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Author:            The WordPress Contributors
 * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       random-jokes
 *
 * @package           create-block
 */

/**
 * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
 * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
 * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
 */

function create_block_random_jokes_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_random_jokes_block_init' );

//setup
function Joke_block_value(){

    global $jokescategory;
    $jokes_array = ['url'=>'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=' . $jokescategory];
    wp_register_script( 'joke-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/build/scripts.js', array(), '1.90.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('joke-script');
    wp_localize_script( 'joke-script', 'joke_value',$jokes_array);
    
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','Joke_block_value');`

Here is my block.json code : 

`{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "create-block/random-jokes",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Random Jokes",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "attributes": {
        "joke":{"type":"string"},
        "category":{
            "type":"string",
            "default":"food"
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "random-jokes",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "viewScript":"file:./scripts.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "render": "file:./render.php"
}
```

Here is my render.php code :

```
<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); 
global $jokescategory;
$jokescategory =  $attributes['category'];
?>>
<p id="joke">
    <?php echo $jokescategory?></p>
</div>
```

here is my scripts.js code :

```
console.log(joke_value)
```

I tried rechecking code. but still unable to find why main plugin file doesn't concatenate the value of $jokescategory in to the console.

```
    $jokes_array = ['url'=>'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=' . $jokescategory];
    wp_localize_script( 'joke-script', 'joke_value',$jokes_array);
```

it's been 5 hours since I am unable to find the solution please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** follow S.Walsh's suggestion and use client-side rendering in JavaScript.

I copied your code exactly (except for the accidental backquotes in the main file and block.json), added an empty `index.js` file for the `editorScript` property in block.json, built the bundles, enabled the plugin, and it worked. The console correctly displayed `Object { url: "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=food" }`.

In the main file, immediately after `global $jokescategory;` is declared, `$jokescategory` had the value *food* (I printed the variable to a file to test).

I did not use *wp-scripts* to build the bundles, but instead used a custom webpack configuration file. I'm using WordPress (6.2-RC2-55551).

For whatever reason S.Walsh's explanation did not apply to my case. However, the advice to use client-side rendering in JavaScript follows what is preferred by WordPress. Look for [Live rendering in the block editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) in the WordPress documentation.

## UPDATE

Your latest solution isn't working because either:

1. the script from the call to `wp_add_inline_script` is not loading (the presence of `jQuery` is assumed and not all WordPress installations use it), or
2. the loading order of the scripts prevents the `joke_category_value` constant from being in scope when needed by `scripts.js`.

Both problems can be solved by manually loading the block.json `viewScript`. Using block.json to automatically enqueue `scripts.js` takes control out of your hands and prevents you from enqueuing the `joke_category_value` constant before the `scripts.js` file. (As an aside: There has been [some discussion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/54018) about adding properties to block.json to control where block scripts are loaded. However, it doesn't appear these new properties have been implemented yet.)

One solution (updated code is below) is to control the enqueuing sequence manually via the `enqueue_block_assets` action hook.

The code below has been tested, and it works except for one problem...

When the client initially requests the WordPress page, no cookie is sent (when session cookies are used), and the plugin has no value stored for `$_SESSION['jokes_category_php']`. Refreshing the window solves the problem because when the client makes a second request, it now has the cookie to send back to the server.

Adding session management might unnecessarily complicate your solution. Therefore, I still recommend the client-side solution offered by S.Walsh.

In `block.json` note the use of the script handle for the `viewScript` property. This handle was registered with the `wp_register_script` function in PHP. Since the script is manually enqueued, the presence of `viewScript` in `block.json` might only be useful as documentation. The block works without it.

#### random-jokes.php(main-plugin-file):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /**
     * Plugin Name:       Random Jokes
     * Description:       Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.
     * Requires at least: 6.1
     * Requires PHP:      7.0
     * Version:           0.1.0
     * Author:            The WordPress Contributors
     * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
     * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
     * Text Domain:       random-jokes
     *
     * @package           create-block
     */

    /**
     * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
     * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
     * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
     *
     * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
     */

    // echo $jokes_category_php;

    global $jokes_category_php_session;
    $jokes_category_php_session = $_SESSION['jokes_category_php'];

    function create_block_random_jokes_block_init()
    {
        register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/build');
    }

    // echo '<h5>' . $jokes_category_php_session . '</h5>';

    function B_scripts()
    {
    }

    add_action('init', 'create_block_random_jokes_block_init');
    add_action('init', 'B_scripts');
    add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'enqueue_block_scripts' );

    // wp_add_inline_script('jquery', 'const joke_category_value = "food"', 'after' );

    /**
     * Enqueue block script manually.
     */
    function enqueue_block_scripts() {
        global $jokes_category_php_session;
        $post_id = \get_the_ID();
        $post = \get_post( $post_id );

        // Assets for create-block/random-jokes.
        if ( ! \is_admin() && is_object( $post ) && \has_block( 'create-block/random-jokes', $post_id ) ) {
            $asset_info = require( \plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/scripts.asset.php' );
            $dependencies = $asset_info['dependencies'];
            $version = $asset_info['version'];

            $inline_script = "const joke_category_value = '${jokes_category_php_session}';";

            \wp_register_script(
                'create-block-random-jokes-script',
                \plugins_url( 'build/scripts.js', __FILE__ ),
                $dependencies,
                $version,
                true
            );

            \wp_add_inline_script( 'create-block-random-jokes-script', $inline_script, 'before' );
            \wp_enqueue_script( 'create-block-random-jokes-script' );
        }
    }
```

#### block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "create-block/random-jokes",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Random Jokes",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "attributes": {
        "joke":{"type":"string"},
        "category":{
            "type":"string",
            "default":"food"
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "random-jokes",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "viewScript": "create-block-random-jokes-script",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "render": "file:./render.php"
}
```

Comment: Great this idea seems to be working. thanks for your help

Comment: This does solve the issue posed but I just want to add I would still be very hesitant to use a global variable for this purpose. Consider the case where the block is used across multiple different posts/pages - should the category always be the same? What if on different pages you want to set a different category.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your function `Joke_block_value()` likely is not needed and obscures the real issue:

- In `Joke_block_value()` the `global $jokescategory;` is initialized as `null`, hence `null` is passed to `$jokes_array`.
- The localized `joke-script` recieves `null` as the function `Joke_block_value()` exists outside of the blocks render callback/scope - it would need to be inside **render.php** to access the default value of your blocks `$attributes`.

How to resolve the issue:

- In **render.php**, use the value of `$attributes['category']` and remove the global variable.
- If the joke is retrieved via AJAX, I would set the value of category as a data attribute and use JS to read the value; removing the need for [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/), eg:

**PHP**

```php
<p id="joke" data-joke-category="<?php echo $attributes['category']; ?>">...</p>
```

If the above scenario is what you are aiming for, having the block render with PHP may be redundant. The markup can be saved via JavaScript with the [`save()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#save) from the Editor, eg:

**JSX**

```js
export default function save({ attributes }) {
    return (
        <p id="joke" data-joke-category={attributes.category}></p>
    );
}
```

Hope this guides you in the right direction...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. you were right wp_localize_script wasn't needed but  I had to use wp_add_inline_script() function . This method worked properly for The logged in users only not the visitors.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late response, I updated my render.php and used session to pass php variable from one file to another but the problem is it works only if a user is logged in and has selected a category from the edit page > Random Jokes block.

[image]

it doesn't work on random users instead I get an error in my console
[image]
Here is the updated codes of these files.The Block.json is unchanged.
Note : I tried using different hooks but it's still not solving that error

**scripts.js**

```
console.log(joke_category_value)
let joke_fetch_api = `https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=${joke_category_value}`;

let jokes_line = document.getElementById('J_joke_block_line_id')
let joke_fetch = fetch(joke_fetch_api);

joke_fetch.then((response) => {
    // console.log(response.status)
    return response.json()
}).then((joke_value) => {
    //   console.log(joke_value['value'])
    jokes_line.innerHTML = joke_value['value']

})
```

**render.php:**

```
<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); 

$jokes_category_php =  $attributes['category'];
$_SESSION['jokes_category_php'] = $attributes['category'];
?>   class="joke_block_main "style=" background:#EDEDED;color:#333333;padding: 60px;
position: relative;
}" class="">
    <div class="category-content">
        <p id="J_joke_block_para_id" class="blockquote">Quote of the Day  </p>
        <p class="text-light otro-blockquote" id="J_joke_block_line_id"><blockquote> - Chuck Norris</blockquote> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**random-jokes.php(main-plugin-file):**

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    /**
     * Plugin Name:       Random Jokes
     * Description:       Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.
     * Requires at least: 6.1
     * Requires PHP:      7.0
     * Version:           0.1.0
     * Author:            The WordPress Contributors
     * License:           GPL-2.0-or-later
     * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
     * Text Domain:       random-jokes
     *
     * @package           create-block
     */
    
    /**
     * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
     * Behind the scenes, it registers also all assets so they can be enqueued
     * through the block editor in the corresponding context.
     *
     * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/
     */
    
    // echo $jokes_category_php;
    
    $jokes_category_php_session = $_SESSION['jokes_category_php'];
    function create_block_random_jokes_block_init()
    {
        register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/build');
        global $jokes_category_php_session;
        wp_add_inline_script('jquery', 'const joke_category_value = "' . "$jokes_category_php_session" . '"', 'before');
    }
    
    // echo '<h5>' . $jokes_category_php_session . '</h5>';
    
    function B_scripts()
    {
    }
    
    add_action('init', 'create_block_random_jokes_block_init');
    add_action('init', 'B_scripts');
    
    // wp_add_inline_script('jquery', 'const joke_category_value = "food"', 'after' );
```

Thanks

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYHXL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBsax.png
```